# Python Tkinter For Loop Widget addressing

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tkinter, widget

I am practicing creating Tkinter widgets in Python using for loops. But if in some case I need to address a widget created under a for loop, how can I do this?

Also, I am confused on how below for loop actually works since it looks like there is only one radio button object created with three copies with different properties. Can someone explain the logic behind how with the same object name we can created three instances?

```
import tkinter as tk

#Window definition    
win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("500x500")

#Radio Button Globals
colors = ["Blue", "Gold", "Red"]

#Radio Button click action
def radCall():
    radSEL = radVar.get()
    if radSEL == 0:
        win.configure(background=COLOR1)
    elif radSEL == 1:
        win.configure(background=COLOR2)
    elif radSEL == 2:
        win.configure(background=COLOR3)   

#Radio Button    
radVar = tk.IntVar() #Radio Button Variable
radVar.set(99) #Select non existened value

for col in range(3):
       rad = tk.Radiobutton(win, text=colors[col], variable=radVar, value=col, command=radCall)
       rad.grid(column=col, row=5, sticky=tk.W)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you done any research? There are many questions on this site related to creating widgets in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rad variable is reassigned each time through the loop, however, tkinter creates a new radiobutton each time through the loop. They all use the same variable `radVar`, which makes them implicitly related. They all have different `value` attributes, so this makes them configured to work well as a radiobutton group.

To answer the question as to how to interact with the button after created, it often recommended to create a dictionary to hold the widgets. For example, the loop could be restructured as follows to give later access to the radio buttons.

```
radio = {}
for col in colors:
    radio[col] = tk.Radiobutton(win, text=colors[col], variable=radVar, value=col, command=radCall)
    radio[col].grid(column=col, row=5, sticky=tk.W)

# Then later you can reconfigure a radiobutton text or something
radio['Red'].configure(text='New text on radio button')
```

Comment: And is there a reason why its a dictionary not a list? I tried the code with a list but, it says the index is out of range when I do it. Can you give me an example with list please?

Comment: The reason to use a dictionary is to make the code more readable. You could use a list as long as you know that the 3rd button is 'red'. Then you refer to the button as radio[2]. I modified the example to make the dictionary advantage more obvious.